# Animate with fade the css style hover state with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

Is it possible to fade animate all css properties of one style with jQuery when hovering? And I mean if you have defined a style and its :hover state only with css, the script to do the rest. Example:

```
.button1 {
background: url(img1.jpg) repeat-x top left;
color: #000;
}
.button1:hover {
background: url(img2.jpg) repeat-x top left;
color: #F00;
}
```

And if you want the jQuery script to do the same to many similar buttons, is it possible? Or the only way is to define two different css styles?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could replace your hover css with a class and use the jquery UI [`ToggleClass`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/toggleClass/) animation:

**css:**

```
.button1:hover,
.button1_hover_class {
  background: url(img2.jpg) repeat-x top left;
  color: #F00;
}
```

**javascript:**

```
$(".button1").hover(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("button1_hover_class", 1000);
    return false;
});
```

If you want to use both the css hover and the javascript hover, I guess you will have to cancel the default action in the javascript `hover` function.

**Edit:** To answer your other question, the javascript above will be applied to all buttons with the `.button1` class but if you would like to add it to `.button2` too, you can use for example:

```
$(".button1, .button2").hover(function() {
```

Comment: I guess this is the heart of the problem. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You will change the css with the animate method and bind that to the hover event.

Comment: Yes, but the idea is to add changes via the css. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

You should try selecting all elements of a class `$(".animates").hover(function(e){})`, for example, and use the [.animate() method from jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) on the `e.target` inside the hover handler.
Example:

```
    <div class="animates">Lipsum</div>
<script>
        $(".animates").hover(function(e){
            $(e.target).animate();
        });
</script>
```

In addition, you can also use css3 transitions, but they're not massively supported yet, so it's safer to stay with jQuery animations unless you know your audience always update their browsers. :P